# It is possible to use a pointer that just match the int value from a float variable in Python?

Tags: c++, python, pointers, floating-point, match

Pointers are not common in Python, neither the var declaration type. I'm triyng to do this in Python.

C++:

```
 ...a function
 flt32 f;
 int32 sign, exp, man, *tms;
 tms = (int *) &f;
 ...(operations)
 *tms = sign | exp | man;
 return (f);
```

as you can see, `tms` points to `f` data, but just the `int` part of the `float` (btw, this function works perfectly).

With ctypes I can use pointers in Python:

```
from ctypes import * 
f = c_float(12.3)
tms = pointer(f) # tms should be: tms = c_int32(value)
print tms.contents.value #12.3000001907
```

The problem here is that `tms` becomes instantly the type of `f`, so both variables are float (`tms` should be `tms = c_int32(a_value))`. 
It is possible to use a pointer that just matches the `int` value from a `float` variable in Python?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do. But I'm almost certain that you're relying on undefined behavior in your C++ example.

Comment: *"Pointers are not common in Python"* - Yes, in fact they don't exist!

Comment: Oh, and: *"but just the int part of the float "* - There is no "int part of [a] float".  You are taking the address of a floating point number and storing that in a pointer to int.  When you dererence that int the `sizeof(int)` bytes that it now points to will be interpreted as if it were an int.

Comment: Undefined behaviour, you are not allowed to access a `float` through an `int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this in Python, you can use ctypes.cast() to cast a float pointer to int pointer, or you can use struct to pack the float value in to a string and unpack it to int. Here is an example:

I use ctypes.cast() to view float value memory as int, and use struct to convert it back:

```
In [5]: from ctypes import *
In [6]: f = c_float(12.3)
In [8]: tmp = cast(pointer(f), POINTER(c_int)) 
In [9]: tmp.contents
Out[9]: c_long(1095027917)
In [10]: tmp.contents.value
Out[10]: 1095027917
In [11]: hex(tmp.contents.value)
Out[11]: '0x4144cccd'

In [13]: import struct
In [16]: struct.unpack("f",struct.pack("I", 1095027917))
Out[16]: (12.300000190734863,)
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you need, to get the integer part of a float number? just do this, then:

```
i = int(afloat)
```